# Evaluate each element of sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

In python, if I have a matrix `a` of integers, I can evaluate it like this.
`b = a > 0`. It would give me a matrix `b` same shape of `a` with boolean values in it indicating whether each value in `a` is larger than 0.

Is there a way to include the index of an element in `a` in the evaluation? Like `b = a > 0 and a.index[0] == 0`. Meaning it will only evaluate elements in the first row of `a`. Other rows will all be placed with `False`.

I want to generate `b` the fastest way.

Comment: You can do `b = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=bool); b[0] = a[0] > 0`...